# using netcat command not able to check open ports correctly

Tags: linux, bash

i have created one shell script for checking open ports on multiple servers.i have used netcat command for the same.But after execution this schows wrong output even ports are open on perticular server.
example. I have tried for 8880,84443 ports , On server thports are open but my script shows wrong output.
My code :
for server in `more input.txt`
do
nc -zvw3 $server $port >> output.txt 2>&1
done

Answer (score 0):

!/bin/sh
echo ""
echo ""
rm -rf output.txt
rm -rf final.txt

echo "$(tput setaf 5)***   PORT CHECKING SCRIPT  *****"
echo ""
echo ""

echo "$(tput setaf 2)Enter Port Number which you want to check : $(tput setaf 7)"
read port

echo ""
echo ""

echo "$(tput setaf 2)Script is running... Wait for some time..."
echo ""

sleep 2

for server in `more input.txt`
do
nc -zvw3 $server $port >> output.txt 2>&1
done

grep -i Connected output.txt >>  final.txt

echo "$(tput setaf 2)You have Entered Port :  "$port
echo ""
echo "$(tput setaf 2)On BelowServers Entered Port is Open "

sleep 1

echo "$(tput setaf 3)"
echo ""
cat final.txt
echo ""
echo "$(tput setaf 5)***  Thank You ...! *****"
#sed 's/connected to/ /g' output.txt >> final.txt
echo "$(tput setaf 7)"

above is the complete code. kindly assist. for port 8880 , 8443 script shows wrong output even these ports are open on server.